# ternary operation on list-view is not working on nativescript

Tags: nativescript

ternary operation on binding element on list view is not working.

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=xMm9oJ&v=2

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
                <Image src="{{ imageSrc }}" class="thumb img-circle" />
                <Label text="{{ name = 'Spain' ? 'INDIA' : name }}" class="list-group-item-heading"
                    verticalAlignment="center" style="width: 60%" />
            </FlexboxLayout>
```

```
countries: [
      { name: "Australia", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/au.png" },
      { name: "Belgium", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/be.png" },
      { name: "Bulgaria", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/bg.png" },
      { name: "Canada", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ca.png" },
      { name: "Switzerland", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ch.png" },
      { name: "China", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/cn.png" },
      { name: "Czech Republic", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/cz.png" },
      { name: "Germany", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/de.png" },
      { name: "Spain", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/es.png" },
      { name: "Ethiopia", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/et.png" },
      { name: "Croatia", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/hr.png" },
      { name: "Hungary", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/hu.png" },
      { name: "Italy", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/it.png" },
      { name: "Jamaica", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/jm.png" },
      { name: "Romania", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ro.png" },
      { name: "Russia", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/ru.png" },
      { name: "United States", imageSrc: "https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/flags/us.png" },
    ],
```

i have tried  to show india instead of spain but i'm not succeed. if it is not possible then how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ternary operation will work based on condition. if it's result is true or false then it will work fine. so, one must be very careful when writing condition statement. since in the code instead of  == it is written  = . that's the reason it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add an extra `=` to your operator. Looks like you're actually assigning INDIA to as name of every name property you have there

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
    <Image src="{{ imageSrc }}" class="thumb img-circle" />
    <Label text="{{ name === 'Spain' ? 'INDIA' : name }}" class="list-group-item-heading"
        verticalAlignment="center" style="width: 60%" />
</FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid curly braces and use binding syntax. It's cleaner.

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
    <Image [src]="imageSrc" class="thumb img-circle" />
    <Label [text]="name === 'Spain' ? 'INDIA' : name" class="list-group-item-heading"
        verticalAlignment="center" style="width: 60%" />
</FlexboxLayout>
```